# Generate global extent hexagon grid tessellation in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, global, hexagonal-grid

I am trying to generate a global hexagon grid at 1 km2 resolution spanning the entire globe as an equal area grid using ArcGIS Pro's 'Generate Tessellation' function. I've tried it in different CRSs using a variety of global layers (polygons and points) to set the extend ('as specified below') but I keep getting an out-of-bounds error or the tessellation generated is empty. How can this best be achieved?

Comment: How are you setting the extent parameter? "Same as display" based on the map, or are you providing some actual values? Maybe you can get the Python snippet of your failed execution and attach it to your post.

Comment: A 1km/hexagon grid spanning the globe would generate over a half a billion individual polygons, and the majority of features would not *look* hexagonal, since there would distortion as the meridians merged toward the poles.

Comment: Not an answer - but I just generated 1000km2 hexagons for the entire world: it did work, creating about 2mil polygons, taking 11minutes. Based on my extent, it created what would probably be overlapping hexagons (if displayed on a globe) as East-West, but I didn't go over 90N. I wonder if your North/South is out of bounds?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I'm aware that it will be a very large dataset but before I can worry about that I need to solve how to get a global grid. I've tried setting parameters manually and from the extent of different loaded global extent shapefiles ('as specified below').